# How to push lines from Line Reader to an array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, request, fs

I am stumped by this problem I am having. I am trying to push an object containing substrings of each line of a text file to an array outside of the scope of fs linereader. I'm nearly positive my array is in the correct scope, but my Array always comes out empty.

The code runs without any errors, I can even print out each line from the text file no problem.

I am trying to use Node to get lines from a text log file and push individual pieces of each line to a db.

```
var watcher = chokidar.watch("MyFolder", {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});
watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {
    var myArray = [];
    console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream(path)
    });
    lineReader.on('line', function (l) {
      l.toString();   
      myArray.push({
        "date" : l.substring(25,35),
        "time" : l.substring(35,46)
       });
    });
    console.log(myArray); //Always empty
  })
  .on('change', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been changed');})
  .on('unlink', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');})
  .on('error', function(error) {console.log('Error happened', error);});
```

I expect the console to show me the array, but it's always empty.

Comment: Of course it's empty, keep in mind that `lineReader.on('line'` registers a callback function that will be executed in the future event-loops, while your `console.log` gets executed in the current event-loop... In other words: you are logging just after you registered the callback function, which has not been executed yet...

Comment: Ah! Thanks I didn't take that into account with callbacks. It's that they're running asynchronously right? I think I'm using that term correctly. I'm playing around with it a bit, but could I wrap this in a Promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting empty array is because ReadLine adds callback into the `IO event queue` and it will be executed after the current executing script completion is done. So it looks like defining the array and printing it on next line. In order to print all values in a array you just need to add one more listener on lineReader `ReadLine object` for `close` event.

Below is the updated code with `close` event.

```
var watcher = chokidar.watch("MyFolder", {ignored: /^\./, persistent: true});
watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {
    var myArray = [];
    console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream(path)
    });
    lineReader.on('line', function (l) {
      l.toString();   
      myArray.push({
        "date" : l.substring(25,35),
        "time" : l.substring(35,46)
       });
    });

    lineReader.on('close', function () {
      console.log(myArray);
    })

  })
  .on('change', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been changed');})
  .on('unlink', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');})
  .on('error', function(error) {console.log('Error happened', error);});
```

Comment: Ah, I thought I needed a Promise or something. Obviously, I overthought this. Thank you!